# Essential Spectrum of Unitary Equivalent Operators are Equal?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I have been following the book "Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics I: Functional Analysis - Reed & Simon", and I got some doubts concerning the topics of the book but are not considered in the book.

Given two operators $A$ and $B$ unitary equivalents, this is, there exist an unitary operator $U$ such that
$$UAU^{-1}=B.$$
Is it true that $\sigma_{ess}(A)=\sigma_{ess}(B)?$

While it is easy to see that $\sigma(A)=\sigma(B)$, the question considering essential spectrums is not so clear for me.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Everything mentioned in the definition of essential spectrum is invariant under unitary equivalence, so yes, it is true.